# How to append input to sha256sum

Tags: cat, input, hashsum

I want to type in `sha256sum`, then `<< cat`, so that I can enter in some word and then receive the output as the hash. But I can't do this because it shows me no file called cat, or shows me a blank `>`. How can I enter `sha256sum` then type in something and the receive the hash?

Answer (score 1):

Run `sha256sum`:

```
$ sha256sum
Hello
```

followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (twice, and don’t press enter)

```
Hello185f8db32271fe25f561a6fc938b2e264306ec304eda518007d1764826381969  -
```

The sum is 185f8db32271fe25f561a6fc938b2e264306ec304eda518007d1764826381969.

Comment: Oh... Sorry noob here..., didn't know it was that easy

Comment: No worries, we’re all here to learn!